# in Spring boot handle multiple exceptions with one @ExceptionHandler for enum validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, error-handling, enums

I have implemented two enum classes as parameters of the UserDTO class that is received as input in the RestController

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.example.enumhandler.exception.NotValidEnumTypeException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

public enum GenderTypeEnum {

    MALE("male"),
    FEMALE("female");


    private final String value;


    private GenderTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
        return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String[] getNamesValue(){
        return Arrays
                .stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).value)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static GenderTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (GenderTypeEnum category : GenderTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new NotValidEnumTypeException(
                "Unknown enum type "
                        + value
                        + ", allowed values are "
                        + Arrays.toString(getNamesValue()));
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.enumerator;

import com.example.enumhandler.exception.NotValidEnumTypeException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import java.util.Arrays;

public enum HobbyTypeEnum {

    BIKE("bike"),
    CLIMB("climb"),
    TENNIS("tennis");

    private final String value;

    private HobbyTypeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getGender(){
        return this.value;
    }

    private static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
        return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String[] getNamesValue(){
        return Arrays
                .stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).value)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static HobbyTypeEnum fromValues(String value) {
        for (HobbyTypeEnum category : HobbyTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (category.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }
        throw new NotValidEnumTypeException(
                "Unknown enum type "
                        + value
                        + ", allowed values are "
                        + Arrays.toString(getNamesValue()));
    }

}
```

At this point, I have created a custom Exception to handle the exception in case the values passed are incorrect compared to those contained by the various Enum classes

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import java.io.Serial;

public class NotValidEnumTypeException extends RuntimeException{

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NotValidEnumTypeException() {
        super();

    }

    public NotValidEnumTypeException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public NotValidEnumTypeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public NotValidEnumTypeException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.example.enumhandler.dto;

import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.GenderTypeEnum;
import com.example.enumhandler.enumerator.HobbyTypeEnum;
import com.example.enumhandler.validator.ValidGenderTypeEnum;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Max;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserDTO {


    private String name;

    @Min(18)
    @Max(25)
    private Integer age;

    @NotNull
    private GenderTypeEnum gender;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private List<HobbyTypeEnum> hobby;

}
```

Finally, I created an @RestControllerAdvice to handle the exception:

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;


import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class UserExceptionHandler {


    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NotValidEnumTypeException.class})
    public final ResponseEntity<?> handleInvalidEnumTypeArgument(
            NotValidEnumTypeException ex
    ){

        HttpStatus badRequest = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        final Throwable rootCause = org
                .apache
                .commons
                .lang3
                .exception
                .ExceptionUtils
                .getRootCause(ex);

        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(rootCause.getLocalizedMessage());

        ErrorResponse error = ErrorResponse
                .builder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(badRequest.getReasonPhrase())
                .code(badRequest.value())
                .message(details)
                .build();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, badRequest);
    }
}
```

with a custom error message

```
package com.example.enumhandler.exception;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;


@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
class ErrorResponse {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private String status;
    private int code;
    private List<String> message;

}
```

Everything works but I would like if two or more Enums are wrong a unique message is returned that catches all these exceptions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some time trying to figure out how the Jackson throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, I find out that Jackson will not continue to deserialize the next field if an exception thrown when deserializing current field. Therefore, we have to ignore and store exceptions thrown when deserializing fields. Then throw those exception after the deserialization completed. First, we have to create a context holder to store exceptions separately for each user.

```
@UtilityClass
public class RequestBodyExceptionHolder {

    public static final Object DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED = null;

    /**
     * Thread local helps us to store exceptions separately for each request.
     */
    private static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Throwable>> context = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private static Map<String, Throwable> getExceptionsFromContext() {
        Map<String, Throwable> data = context.get();
        if (data == null) {
            data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            context.set(data);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static Map<String, Throwable> getStoredExceptions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(getExceptionsFromContext());
    }

    public static void clearExceptions() {
        context.remove();
    }

    public static void collectFailedFieldWhileDeserialization(final JsonParser parser, final Throwable exception) throws IOException {
        final Map<String, Throwable> exceptions = getExceptionsFromContext();
        final String fieldName = Optional.ofNullable(parser.getCurrentName()).orElseGet(() -> parser.getParsingContext().getParent().getCurrentName());
        exceptions.put(fieldName, exception);
    }

}
```

Now, you have to catch those exception thrown when deserialization and store those. We should return null when deserialization failed.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
        jsonMapper.addHandler(new RequestBodySilenceDeserializationProblemHandler());

        return jsonMapper;
    }

    static class RequestBodySilenceDeserializationProblemHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {
        @Override
        public Object handleInstantiationProblem(final DeserializationContext context, final Class<?> instClass, final Object argument, final Throwable exception) throws IOException {
            final JsonParser parser = context.getParser();
            RequestBodyExceptionHolder.collectFailedFieldWhileDeserialization(parser, exception);
            return RequestBodyExceptionHolder.DEFAULT_VALUE_WHEN_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED;
        }
    }
}
```

After the deserialization succeed, you have to throw all exceptions that we have stored:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestAdvisor {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(@NonNull final WebDataBinder binder) {
        final Map<String, Throwable> exceptions = RequestBodyExceptionHolder.getStoredExceptions();
        if (!exceptions.isEmpty()) {
            RequestBodyExceptionHolder.clearExceptions();
            throw new RequestBodyDeserializationException(exceptions);
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class RequestBodyDeserializationException extends RuntimeException {
    
        private final Map<String, Throwable> errors;
    
    }
}
```

Then, add custom exception handler for the `RequestBodyDeserializationException`:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(RequestAdvisor.RequestBodyDeserializationException.class)
    public static ResponseEntity<?> handleRequestBodyDeserializationException(
        @NonNull final RequestAdvisor.RequestBodyDeserializationException exception
    ) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

        final List<String> details = exception
            .getErrors()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(cause -> ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(cause).getLocalizedMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        ...

    }
```

And lastly, make sure to clean up the context after your request is proceed:

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        @NonNull final HttpServletRequest request,
        @NonNull final HttpServletResponse response,
        @NonNull final FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        
        // Clear exceptions that stored in context
        RequestBodyExceptionHolder.clearExceptions();
    }
}
```

This is the output that I have achieved, hope it helps you:
[image]